# PHP Closure class gives Fatal error?

Tags: php, closures

I am getting this:

> ***PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Closure::bind()***

The line where I get the error is:

```
public function bind($signal, $callback)
{

    if (!array_key_exists($signal, $this->_registry))
        $this->_registry[$signal] = array();
    $this->_registry[$signal][] = \Closure::bind($callback, null, 'static'); // here

    return $this;
}
```

As you can see I use the `Closure::bind()`as it is showed in the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php). Please note that I am using `\Closure::bind()` (note the slash) because I use namespace autoloading and it is needed to inform the autoloader that it should look into the system namespace.

***NOTE***

Look carefully at each class in the documentation and pay attention to every detail :)

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: What version of PHP is on your server?

Comment: Version 5.3.16 is on the localhost

Comment: @DaGhostmanDimitrov: There's your problem right there!  You need 5.4 for this to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your php version, clearly you are not on >= 5.4.0!

Comment: ok why in the __construct it says that the min version is >= 5.3.0 :D

Comment: Closures exist in 5.3, but the methods were added in 5.4 :]

Comment: You have to be careful with new stuff like this; they like to extend their classes in later updates!

Comment: ty for the clearance :D and for the fast response all :) Yh I was looking only at the constructor... and thought that the whole class it there :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that the method is supported by your PHP version.
You can check method existence with the `method_exists()` command. The method you are trying to execute **only works with PHP 5.4.0 or higher!**

For more information on checking method existence look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php

Comment: it is not a function it is a method :) and the proper way to check is not with function exists, but with `new ReflectionClass(Object)::hasMethod($methodName);`

Comment: yh +1 for the easier way :D

Answer (score -1):

You need to check your PHP version. The documentation states that the version should be atleast 5.4.0

Link:-  [Closure](http://www.php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php)

Comment: I would argue .. cuz the error is that the method does not exist :)

Comment: Oh... yes i got it. My bad ;)

Comment: @Vivek: maybe add a documentation link. :-)